# How to use 'find_elements_by_xpath' inside a for loop

Tags: selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup

I'm somewhat (or very) confused about the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome()

html_content = """
<html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
         <div class='first'>
             Text 1
         </div>
         <div class="second">
             Text 2
                 <span class='third'> Text 3 
                 </span>              
         </div>
         <div class='first'>
             Text 4
         </div>
         <my_tag class="second">
             Text 5
                 <span class='third'> Text 6
                 </span>              
         </my_tag>
     </body>
</html>
"""
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))
```

What I'm trying to do, is find each `span` element using xpath, print out its text and then print out the text of the parent of that element. The final output should be something like:

```
Text 3
Text 2
Text 6
Text 5
```

I can get the text of `span` like this:

```
el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("*//span")
for i in el:
   print(i.text)
```

With the output being:

```
Text 3
Text 6
```

But when I try to get the parent's (and only the parent's) text by using:

```
elp = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("*//span/..")
for i in elp:
   print(i.text)
```

The output is:

```
Text 2 Text 3
Text 5 Text 6
```

The xpath expressions `*//span/..`and `//span/../text()` usually (but not always, depending on which xpath test site is being used) evaluate to:

```
Text 2
Text 5
```

which is what I need for my `for` loop.

Hence the confusion. So I guess what I'm looking for is a `for` loop which, in pseudo code, looks like:

```
 el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("*//span")
 for i in el:
    print(i.text)
    print(i.parent.text) #trying this in real life raises an error....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a few ways to do this. Here's one way

```
elp = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.third")
for i in elp:
    print(i.text)
    s = i.find_element_by_xpath("./..").get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(s.split('<')[0].strip())
```

I used a simple CSS selector to find the child elements ("text 3" and "text 6"). I loop through those elements and print their `.text` as well as navigate up one level to find the parent and print its text also. As OP noted, printing the parent text also prints the child. To get around this, we need to get the innerHTML, split it and strip out the spaces.

To explain the XPath in more detail

```
./..
^ start at an existing node, the 'i' in 'i.find_element_*'. If you skip/remove this '.', you will start at the top of the DOM instead of at the child element you've already located.
 ^ go up one level, to find the parent
```

Comment: It definitely looks promising, but it seems that the 'navigate up one level' doesn't quite work, in that the output is exactly the same as the `elp = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("*//span/..")` statement in the question: `Text 3, Text2 Text 3, Text 6, Text 5 Text 6`. We need to find a way to suppress the printing of the second part of the `text` of `..`.

Comment: Yep.. you are right. I forgot that the parent also contains the child element. Is there some reason you don't want to grab the parent and split the two by newline? It would be a LOT easier.

Comment: Of course; we can do string manipulations here, but by now (with all the thought I gave this problem) it became a matter of principle (as it were) to find a more organic method to do that, if one exists.

Comment: I fixed the answer. Try that. I parsed the innerHTML of the parent to split out the child. I tested it locally but you will need to test it on the real system to ensure that it's working.

Comment: OK, it does work! Thanks. Just occurred to me - is there a way to use `unwrap()` to get there?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with `unwrap()`. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I know I already accepted @JeffC's answer, but in the course of working on this question something occurred to me. It's very likely an overkill, but it's an interesting approach and, for the sake of future generations, I figured I might as well post it here as well.

The idea involves using BeautifulSoup. The reason is that BS has a couple of methods for erasing nodes from the tree. One of them which can be useful here (and for which, to my knowledge, Selenium doesn't have an equivalent method) is `decompose()` ([see more here)](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose). We can use `decompose()` to suppress the printing of the second part of the `text` of the parent, which is contained inside a `span` tag by eliminating the tag and its content. So we import BS and start with @JeffC's answer:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
elp = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.third")

for i in elp:
    print(i.text)
    s = i.find_element_by_xpath("./..").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

and here switch to bs4

```
    content = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
    content.find('span').decompose()
    print(content.text)
```

And the output, without string manipulation, regex, or whatnot is...:

```
Text 3   
      Text 2

Text 6
      Text 5
```

Comment: The right tool for the right job... many times there's more than one tool available. Knowing which one to use sometimes is the hardest to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

i.parent.text will not work, in java i used to write some thing like

```
 ele.get(i).findElement("here path to parent may be parent::div ").getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the python method that will retrieve the text from only parent node.

```
def get_text_exclude_children(element):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    textValue += child.textContent;
                    child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;""",
        element).strip()
```

This is how to use the method in your case:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.third")
for eleNum in range(len(elements)):
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='third'])[" + str(eleNum+1) +"]").text)
    print(get_text_exclude_children(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='third'])[" + str(eleNum+1) +"]/parent::*")))
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Interesting approach, but `return self.driver.execute_script` raised `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

Comment: My bad, forgot to remove that `self`. Updated the answer, just removed self. So you should be good to execute the method now.

Comment: Now I'm getting this strange error (never seen it before): `StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`. I refreshed everything and tried again, but the error sticks.

Comment: Hmm, Updated the code to use the index rather element to point the parent. Hope you should be good with this change :-)

Comment: At least the error this time is more recognizable :) `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//span[@class='third'])[0]"}`.

Comment: Try one last time, I updated the answer. Tested the code and it's working ` have to increment the eleNumber by one, as it's starts with `0` and xpath index starts with 1.

Comment: Sorry, still the same error. I don't know what the problem is. I'm using Jupyter, fwiw. I'll try again tonight on a different machine and IDE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192595/discussion-between-supputuri-and-jack-fleeting).